# How can I run tests in parallels using xdist with single Launch?

Tags: selenium, pytest, reportportal

When I launch my tests in parallel using python-xdist library, several launches are created in report portal.

How can I parallel my tests with single Launch?

My test:

```
def test_RP():
    assert True == True

def test_RP2():
    assert True == False
```

When I run test:

```
py.test -n 2 -v -s  tests/home/login_test.py --rp-launch LoginGmailParallel
```

3 different launches are created in RP (1 is empty):

[RP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljGsg.png)

Comment: Can you share more details about your test setup?
Do you have pytest.ini and/or conftest.py?
It's not clear what causing this from the code you shared.
Also you passed  `-n 2` which will create 2 test executors but you stated that you had 3 `launches` ... this may not be a pytest problem but some plugins/libs that you use.

Comment: @DmitryTokarev I've updated the summary. Yes, I have pytest.ini but it  contains only setup parameters for report portal (host, port, uuid, etc.) 
According your second comment: -n 2 it's a parameter for launch tests with xdist library on 2 CPU. 
After debugging I've found that first launch was created after plugins initialization (before session was started), second and third relate to each slave nodes which xdist created. It seems like when each node configures - all plugins re-initialize. 
Maybe you know how can I prevent initialization of specific plugin for slave node?

Comment: @DmitryTokarev ^

Comment: @DzmitryHumianiuk sorry for late reply. I don't use reportportal. But i use Pytest framework a lot. So from my exeperience it all looks like there is a misconfiguration of the reportportal or there is a bug in reportportal plugin. Sorry i can't help any further. Try and look in existing issues on reportportal project.
Also as a side note, please embed screenshots in your stackoverflow post instead of the linking to a 3rd party service.

Comment: oh, i just saw that https://github.com/DzmitryHumianiuk is part of reportportal org on github. You guys should just ask pytest dev team for help on this: https://github.com/pytest-dev they are great folks and could help figuring this out. Good luck!